# Trigger script when duplicate a record filemaker

Tags: duplicates, filemaker

I am trying to trigger a script when a user duplicate record in a layout in filemaker 13. But I can not capture this action. Anyone have any ideas about how to do this?

Thank you so much,

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: With FM Pro Advanced you could write a Script and then use Custom Menus to override the Duplicate Record menu item. Regular FM Pro doesn't give you the same options, so knowing more about what you are trying to do, in particular, might be helpful to suggest work-arounds.

Comment: What I want to do is when an user duplicate an purchase order record, I want to delete the date of this order. Because it will not be the same. However, I do not know how to capture when user duplicate it.

Answer (score 0):

One answer to the question, as asked, is to use FileMaker Pro 13 Advanced. The custom menus feature will allow you to override the Duplicate Record menu function with your own script.

However, per your comments, it sounds like the true question you're trying to answer is: "How do I clear a field when a record is duplicated?"

You can do this in either FileMaker Pro or FileMaker Pro Advanced by setting the field's Auto-Enter Data value to blank. Then each new record will have the field cleared when the record is created.

You can do this in the following way (there may be some minor variations for Windows computers):

```
Go to:  File Menu > Manage Submenu > Database...
Select: Your Table and then your Date Field from the Fields tab
Click:  The options button (with your Date field selected)
Check:  The Data checkbox within the Auto-Enter tab, leaving the data field blank
```

Comment: Or set the field to auto-enter the current date.